# Can we use REST API built on WCF and ASP.net with Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, rest-api, soap-api

Just for knowledge, will these APIs would be compatible with M2 and we use them in same way as we use other APIs designed for Magento 2? or there would be some other way to use them ?